# Passing pointer to C array to a function

Tags: c

What do I misunderstand about passing pointers to char arrays?

```
Request pointer in fun: 0x7fffde9aec80
Response pointer in fun: 0x7fffde9aec80
Response pointer: (nil), expected: 0x7fffde9aec80
Response itself: (null), expected: Yadda
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_response(char *request, char **response) {
    response = &request;
    printf("Request pointer in fun: %p\n", request);
    printf("Response pointer in fun: %p\n", *response);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char *response = NULL, request[] = "Yadda";

    get_response(request, &response);

    printf("Response pointer: %p, expected: %p\n", response, request);
    printf("Response itself: %s, expected: %s\n", response, request);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know.  Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: He doesn't get why what gets printed does not match what he 'expects' to be printed:

`Response pointer: (nil), expected: 0x7fffde9aec80
Response itself: (null), expected: Yadda`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the function `get_response` you store the address of `request` in the temporary variable `response`. You want to store it where `response` *points* to.

```
*response = request;
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what OP is 'misunderstanding'. i.e. changing an argument's value instead of changing the location which the argument points to.

Answer (score 0):

Try `*response = request`: you want to set the contents of the response pointer to the request content.

Answer (score 0):

You want `*response = request;` instead of `response = &request;` in `get_response(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with the currect declaration and your usage of `get_response`, the parameter `response` is declared as `char**`, which is a pointer to a `char*`, e.g. a pointer to a pointer. This would be useful if you somehow needed to modify the pointer actually pointing to the memory containing your `response`, but in this case this is not needed.